# API Platform POST embedded document in ManyToMany relation using id (not IRIs)

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, api-platform.com

I have 2 entities, BlogPost and Category, which is have many to many relation. In order to make post request, is it possible to just reference id of entity, in this case category_id, when I want to make post request for BlogPost ?

Pattern like this, using IRI reference **works**

```
{
  "title": "Post new",
  "createdAt": "2020-11-03T11:03:04.930Z",
  "excerpt": "Excerpt doc",
  "content": "Content doc",
  "slug": "post-new",
  "categories": [
    {"/api/categories/1"},
    {"/api/categories/2"}
  ],
  "thumbnail": "string"
}
```

But pattern like this, **still problem**

```
{
  "title": "Post new",
  "createdAt": "2020-11-03T11:03:04.930Z",
  "excerpt": "Excerpt doc",
  "content": "Content doc",
  "slug": "post-new",
  "categories": [
    {"id": 1},
    {"id": 2}
  ],
  "thumbnail": "string"
}
```

Here my **BlogPost** entity:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use App\Repository\BlogPostRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *     itemOperations={
 *          "get",
 *          "put",
 *          "delete"
 *      },
 *     collectionOperations={
 *          "get",
 *          "post"
 *      },
 *     normalizationContext={
 *          "groups"={"blogpost:read"}
 *      },
 *     denormalizationContext={
 *          "groups"={"blogpost:write"}
 *      },
 *     shortName="posts"
 * )
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=BlogPostRepository::class)
 */
class BlogPost
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Groups({"blogpost:read", "blogpost:write"})
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     * @Groups({"blogpost:read", "blogpost:write"})
     */
    private $createdAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     * @Groups({"blogpost:read", "blogpost:write"})
     */
    private $excerpt;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     * @Groups({"blogpost:read", "blogpost:write"})
     */
    private $content;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Groups({"blogpost:read", "blogpost:write"})
     */
    private $slug;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Category::class, inversedBy="post", cascade={"persist"})
     * @Groups({"blogpost:read", "blogpost:write"})
     */
    private $categories;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     * @Groups({"blogpost:read", "blogpost:write"})
     */
    private $thumbnail;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->categories = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getTitle(): ?string
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    public function setTitle(string $title): self
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCreatedAt(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    public function setCreatedAt(\DateTimeInterface $createdAt): self
    {
        $this->createdAt = $createdAt;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getExcerpt(): ?string
    {
        return $this->excerpt;
    }

    public function setExcerpt(?string $excerpt): self
    {
        $this->excerpt = $excerpt;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getContent(): ?string
    {
        return $this->content;
    }

    public function setContent(string $content): self
    {
        $this->content = $content;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getSlug(): ?string
    {
        return $this->slug;
    }

    public function setSlug(string $slug): self
    {
        $this->slug = $slug;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Category[]
     */
    public function getCategories(): Collection
    {
        return $this->categories;
    }

    public function addCategory(Category $category): self
    {
        if (!$this->categories->contains($category)) {
            $this->categories[] = $category;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeCategory(Category $category): self
    {
        if ($this->categories->contains($category)) {
            $this->categories->removeElement($category);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function getThumbnail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->thumbnail;
    }

    public function setThumbnail(?string $thumbnail): self
    {
        $this->thumbnail = $thumbnail;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

And here my **Category** entity

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use App\Repository\CategoryRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;

/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *     itemOperations={"get", "delete", "put"},
 *     collectionOperations={"get", "post"},
 *     normalizationContext={"groups"={"category:read"}},
 *     denormalizationContext={"groups"={"category:write"}},
 * )
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=CategoryRepository::class)
 */
class Category
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Groups({"category:read"})
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
     * @Groups({
     *      "category:read",
     *      "category:write"
     * })
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
     * @Groups({
     *      "category:read",
     *      "category:write"
     * })
     */
    private $slug;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=BlogPost::class, mappedBy="categories")
     * @Groups({"category:read", "blogpost:write"})
     */
    private $post;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->post = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getSlug(): ?string
    {
        return $this->slug;
    }

    public function setSlug(string $slug): self
    {
        $this->slug = $slug;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|BlogPost[]
     */
    public function getPost(): Collection
    {
        return $this->post;
    }

    public function addPost(BlogPost $post): self
    {
        if (!$this->post->contains($post)) {
            $this->post[] = $post;
            $post->addCategory($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removePost(BlogPost $post): self
    {
        if ($this->post->contains($post)) {
            $this->post->removeElement($post);
            $post->removeCategory($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

What the essential configuration to achieve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

cant comment yet but i'm pretty sure the post body is supposed to be

```
{
  "title": "Post new",
  "createdAt": "2020-11-03T11:03:04.930Z",
  "excerpt": "Excerpt doc",
  "content": "Content doc",
  "slug": "post-new",
  "categories": [
    "/api/categories/1",
    "/api/categories/2"
  ],
  "thumbnail": "string"
}
```

Comment: Thanks I use this route for my Entity: /api/categories/1

Answer (score 0):

Just use the groups provided by serializer.

Define the group "BlogPost" on each property you want to expose (so for your Category entity, only $id)
And then, call the normalization (or serialization, depending on what you need) with the named group :

```
$serializer->normalize($chunk, null, ["groups" => "BlogPost"]);

$serializer->serialize($post, 'json', ['groups' => 'BlogPost']);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've added `@Groups({"blogpost:read", "blogpost:write"})` on field id in Category. And got errors `A new entity was found through the relationship 'App\\Entity\\BlogPost#categories' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity`

Comment: uh, yeah, it's because, your `categories` property in BlogPost is defined as cascade=persist, so it mean that if it detect some values on this variable, it will cast into Category entity. But, because we made a group which exclude all properties excepct `ìd`, doctrine is lost because he don't recognize that Category properties ... So like that, i'm not sure that i can help you more. Maybe could you try to remove the cascade= persist option on `App\\Entity\\BlogPost#categories` maybe it will work, but fore sure you'll have other problem otherwhere ; just a temporary solution.

Comment: Cool man, tx again. Here I've added cascade on BlogPost#categories `* @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Category::class, inversedBy="post", cascade={"persist"})` and still got error like this `An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO category (name, slug) VALUES (?, ?)' with params [null, null]:\n\nSQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 NOT NULL constraint failed: category.name`

Comment: Oh ya, actually I've been tried add Groups write to field cat_name & cat_slug, then use those fields included on BlogPost embedded POST resource, its success created new post, but new category also created. How to embedded just id, that what i need and also not created new one

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use a custom controller for that.

```
 *   collectionOperations={
 *          "post"={
 *              "method"="POST",
 *              "controller"=PostAdd::class,
 *          }
 *     }
```

for more details
https://api-platform.com/docs/core/controllers/